# Switching views with Alamofire result and present()

Tags: swift

I am trying to make an authentication (login) screen for my app. I use Alamofire and SwiftyJson. But I tried every single solution that come to mind to solve my problem.

The error I get: Attempt to present viewcontroller on  whose viewController is not in the window hierarchy!

Problem: When I hit the login button on my screen, i successfully get the username and password from my service. I use "response.result.isSuccess", so I can authenticate the user to the next page after this step. It is my first time working with alamofire and I couldn't find a solution to this.

Where it occurs: When I get the result from the service(boolean), I want to redirect the user to the next page. I marked it down below with // *********Error*********

I tried to put the request into my controller which ruins my MVC architecture, so I need better way to do it. I have been experiencing this error for 2 days.

My Rest manager class;

```swift
class restManager {
    var requestType: String?
    var page = loginPage()
    var baseURL = "myUrl" // my service url lies down here on my code
    init(type: String){
        self.requestType = type
    }
    func builder(info: userInfo){
        if(requestType == "get"){
            makeGetRequest(path: baseURL, info: info)
        }
    }

    private func makeGetRequest(path: String, info : userInfo) {
        let params : [String: String] = ["sUser" : nm, "sPass" : ps, "sToken": "''"]
        get(parameters: params)
    }

    private func get(parameters: [String: String]){
        Alamofire.request(baseURL, method:.get ,parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
            print("Result: \(response.result)")
            if let json = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(json)")
                self.page.auth(res: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my loginPage view controller;

```swift
class loginPage: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var logo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    private var loginInfo = userInfo()
    private var mng: restManager?
    @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: roundButton) {
        if(usernameTextField.text != "" && passwordTextField.text != ""){
            loginInfo.setUsername(info: usernameTextField.text)
            loginInfo.setPassword(info: passwordTextField.text)
            let mng = restManager(type: "get")
            mng.builder(info: loginInfo)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func auth(res: Bool){
        if (res) {
            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homePageNavCtrl") as! homePageNavCtrl
            self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil) // *********Error********
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Invalid username and password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

I want to show my navigation controller after user login, but it does not happen.

Comment: Please excuse my swift and alamofire knowledge, I am still learning it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the closures/callbacks, so after getting response your success and error callbacks will be called. Here is the example of that method.

```
class func alamofireRequest(URLString: String, parameters : Parameters, method:HTTPMethod, successCallback: @escaping (NSDictionary) -> Void, errorCallBack: @escaping (String) -> Void) -> Void {

    Alamofire.request(URLString, method: method, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
        print(response)
        if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
            print(JSON)
            successCallback(JSON as NSDictionary)
        } else {
            errorCallBack("JSON Doesn't Exist")
        }
    }

}
```

and called this method in your class like

```
 let params : [String: String] = ["sUser" : nm, "sPass" : ps, "sToken": "''"]
        get(parameters: params)

      restManager.alamofireRequest(URLString: url,method:.get parameters: params, successCallback: { (dict) in


                // Yahoo! You get the response do whatever you want


            }) { (error) in


              // Show error

            }
```

Comment: Thanks man, this request function was exactly what I wanted to do. But I still get the error.

Comment: I am getting the same error : Warning: Attempt to present <project.homePageNavCtrl: 0x7fb284898c00> on <project.loginPage: 0x7fb283f559f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: @Fuzzyy now you don't need that variable loginPage in your restManager class. When you get the response , write these line of codes in it.
 let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homePageNavCtrl") as! homePageNavCtrl
            self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil) //

Comment: On the line"self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)", It says "Value of type 'restManager' has no member 'present'", because it is not a viewcontroller.

Comment: @Fuzzyy you should call this line in LoginPage ViewController and also don't use the variable of loginPage.